# Opencv consecutive frames capture from webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam, video-capture, opticalflow

I'm developing a realtime opticalflow app with Opencv (C++).
I don't understand how capture two consecutive frames to apply Lucas-Kanade Tracking method.

This don't work:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
IplImage *imgA=cvQueryFrame( capture );
IplImage *imgB=cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

I also have tried this, but the program does not exit the loop:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
IplImage *imgA=cvQueryFrame( capture );
IplImage *imgB=cvCreateImage(cvSize(imgA),IPL_DEPTH_32F,3);
while(cvNorm(imgA,imgB)==0)
    imgB=cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

Any ideas? I hope this isn't a stupid question, but I suspect that it is :/ Sorry in advance.
Thanks!!

Comment: It's logical it does not exit the loop, as the webcam never stops to feed it in images. Did you try to watch the result in a window, with cvShowImage()?

Comment: I use this QTOpencv APP: [link](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Opencv+webcam+viewer?content=89995)
    cvwidget->putImage(imgA);

Comment: I mean that imgA must capture before imgB and it should not be the same image (unless the camera is not in motion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cv::Mat m1, m2;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

if(!cap.isOpened())
    ;// ... throw error here

cap >> m1;
cap >> m2;

// m1 and m2 now contain consecutive frames.
```

Answer (score 1):

I explain why original code does not work. cvQueryFrame reuses same buffer each time. So when you do:

```
IplImage *imgA=cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

you get pointer to his internal buffer where image is held. Now when doing:

```
IplImage *imgB=cvQueryFrame( capture );
```

image is rewritten and pointer to same buffer is given. ImgA==ImgB. You have to make copy after querying first frame, then everything works.

Answer (score 1):

one query before the loop, and another inside the loop might be enough here
(pseudocode):

```
IplImage prev = query(capture)

while(1)
   next = query(capture )

   opticalflow( prev, next )

   prev = cvCopy( next )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat* mImg;
IplImage* _image;
IplImage* image;
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    _image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
}

*image = *_image;
```

I always meet the situation `0xC0000005` with this. i wonder that is there anything wrong in my code. I use `image = _image`, because I think that `_image = cvQueryFrame(capture);` is just point to the buffer of capture, so I can save the frame in another memory situation.